# mySQL update multiple rows with a single value

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a files table where i want to change the folderName for both of the associated files.
  This is the current data in the table

```
+-------+----------+----------+------------+--------+
|fileID | fileName | folderID | folderName | userID |
+-------+----------+----------+------------+--------+
| 1     | file1    | 1        | folder1    | 1      |
| 2     | file2    | 1        | folder1    | 1      |
+-------+----------+----------+------------+--------+
```

I want the table to update to this after executing a SQL update statement.

```
+-------+----------+----------+------------+--------+
|fileID | fileName | folderID | folderName | userID |
+-------+----------+----------+------------+--------+
| 1     | file1    | 1        | folder2    | 1      |
| 2     | file2    | 1        | folder2    | 1      |
+-------+----------+----------+------------+--------+
```

I want to put an sql statement inside a php function that is called where the parameters are the userID, folderID and folderNewName.

I.e.: an sql update statement where multiple rows of data are updated. I can't find a suitable sql update statement where the `folderName` column is changed for both of the files associated with it, such as changing `folder1` to `folder2` where `folder1` is associated with `file1` and `file2`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @jeroen I want to update the `folderName` data from the values in 1st table preview to the values in the 2nd table preview

Comment: I still don't understand. And an "sql statement", there must be hundreds; [take your pick](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index.html)

Comment: @Fred-ii- an sql update statement where multiple rows of data are updated. I can't find a suitable sql update statement where the folderName is changed for both of the files associated with it, such as changing folder1 to folder2 where folder1 is associated with file1 and file2

Comment: ah, got it now. You mean `folderName` "column". You'd need to use a `JOIN` or something similar to that, and I'm not good with those at all, so I can't help you with that. Yet, I do know it's something along those lines. @user1386999

Comment: Scratch that, you won't need a `JOIN` I thought those were 2 different tables. What you need is a `WHERE` clause. I.e.: `UPDATE table_name SET folderName='folder2' WHERE fileID='2'` pretty sure that would work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have already tried using the 'WHERE' clause but i did not work. it did not update any rows of data. i think the reason is because there are multiple rows and i can't find a suitable sql statement to update multiple rows

Comment: You need to show us your full code then, with what you've tried left intact.

Comment: `UPDATE files SET fileFolder = '$folderName' WHERE folderID = '$folderID' AND userID = '$userID'`

Comment: You don't have a `fileFolder` column named like that in your posted code. And if you want to update multiple columns, you'd need to seperate them with commas. I.e.: `UPDATE table SET column1 = '$var1', column2= '$var2'  WHERE column = '$column_ID' AND column_userID = '$userID'` type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got the question right, are you looking for something like this?

```
UPDATE your_table
SET folderName='$folderNewName'
WHERE userID='$userID' AND folderID='$folderID';
```

Comment: i already tried that but it did not update the table. i think the reason is because there are multiple rows of data.

Comment: Check so your "SET fileFolder" to match the table column "folderName"